# how to get firebase database nested data access inside unique key

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In firebase I want to access database written as below.

[image]

```
<script>
function fnReadMails(){
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var ref = firebase.database().ref('/posts/'+user.uid);
  ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    var vardata = (snapshot.val());
    console.log(vardata);
  });
}
</script>
```

The problem is that string marked in red is unique push key randomly generated. Whenever I am getting a reference I am able to take ref up to one level upper i.e. `userid` , but I want to access data inside that key which I don't know as it will be generated for next post automatically.

How to access nested data inside key?

Comment: @Dravidian javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to Callam's answer, you can also keep using the `value` event. But in that case you must loop over the messages with `forEach()`:

```
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(messageSnapshot) {
    console.log(messageSnapshot.val());
  }
});
```

Both approaches (using `value` vs using `child_*`) result in the same network traffic. But using `value` is often easier to get started with, while using `child_` events makes it easier to update the specific UI element that needs to be updated.

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen; it worked for me but how to store value of nos. of records.

Comment: Has the on function deprecated? It cannot resolve symbol on for me.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `child_added` event type, this will log the snapshot of every child under your ref.

```
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot);
});
```